# Sum of data from a firebase document

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firebase dp data sum

I have a web application and I would like to make a function to add all the integers in the "equipment" field of all the documents in the "epis" collection.

My application is in reactjs.

What's the best way?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWWGz.png)

Comment: Did you try anything yet? The API for Firestore is quite well documented, so it's much more likely we can help if you show what you'd done already.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a pure JS problem. My solution would be to use the JS reduce function on the array of objects after fetching from firestore. i.e.

```
function getSum(total, num) {
        return (total + parseInt(num.equipment));
    }

useEffect(() => {
    var firestoreArray = [...]; //this is populated with the array of objects 
// from firestore when you fetch. format is {name: "shovel", equipment: "12" }

  var total = firestoreArray.reduce(getSum, 0); //reduce function where the 0 is the starting 
//point of the sum. the getSum function is adding by parsing to Integer first for all the 
//objects "equipment" attribute.

}, [firestoreArray]}
```